# Reg Ex to break string

Tags: regex

Can somebody help in correcting my reg ex to get the desired results.  My input text:

Registry-Location: `ht://something:789/pddf`

I want to store following values in separate variables:

```
c1="Registry-Location"
c2="ht://something.com:789/pddf"
```

The regex I am using currently is reading the string from behind and storing the value as:

```
c1="Registry-Location: htt://something.com"
c2="789/pddf"
```

Regex I am using --> `$row=~/(.*):(.*)/;`

Here row is `Registry-Location: htt://something.com:789/pddf`

How can I get my desired results?

Comment: Regex I am using -->  $row=~/(.*):(.*)/;

Comment: If there won't be other colons in the first half, just make your quantifier non-greedy, _i.e._ `/(.*?):(.*)/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex

```
/([^:]*):\s*(.*)/
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB6eB4)